# I am trying to get html tag name on Mouse click into Winforms RichTextbox in CEFSharp but getting null as Exception

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, cefsharp

I am trying to get the Selected Html tag element on mouse click. I am using CEFSharp. For example, when a client will click on the H1 or P tag, the selected HTML tag element name will be on richtextbox.

But In return getting this bellow exception

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

CefSharp.JavascriptResponse.Result.get returned null.
```

This is my demo.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
    industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
    scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
    Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
    PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my script file. I am using jquery.

```js
$('*', document.body).click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    return dotnetMessage.show(event.target.nodeName);
});
```

And here is my winforms C# code

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromium();
        }
        
        public void InitializeChromium()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
            chromeBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Settings.LegacyBindingEnabled = true;
            chromeBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("dotnetMessage", new DotNetMessage(),BindingOptions.DefaultBinder);
            // Add it to the form and fill it to the form window.
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
            chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            chromeBrowser.LoadingStateChanged+= OnLoadingStateChanged;
        }

        private async void OnLoadingStateChanged(object? sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var scriptJsPath = string.Format(@"{0}\script.js", Application.StartupPath);
            var script = File.ReadAllText(scriptJsPath);
            // var script = @"(function(){return 'HALLOOOO'})();"; // this is working

            var result = await chromeBrowser
                .GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync(script)
                .ContinueWith(t => t.Result.Result.ToString());
            richTextBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => { richTextBox1.Text = result; }));
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String page = string.Format(@"{0}\demo.html", Application.StartupPath);
            chromeBrowser.Load(page);
        }
    }

    public class DotNetMessage
    {
        public string Show(string message)
        {
            return message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script would likely evaluate to the jQuery object which is to complex to be parse/represent as a .Net object. So returning null is expected in this case.

The DotNetMessage.Show method should be called with the tag name, you should update your show method to update the richTextBox1.Text property.

For simple message passing I'd suggest using CefSharp.PostMessage instead of binding an object. There is an example at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#JSEvent